Recognition of different barcode readers?
I have two barcode scanners which are connected to a single PC via USB ports. I want to insert data coming from them into SQL Server. How I can know which one of them sends the string?
My Windows Forms app has only one textbox. Barcode scanners are passive devices without any IP or MAC address.

You cant, ususually they simulate keyboard input. So other than them they typing their name or specifying some identifier this won`t be possible. It is basically the same problem as if you wanted to differentiate between multiple people using the same keyboard.
Depending on the specific API and or documentation this could be possible in some way. But using the standard textbox input i highly doubt it.

Most scanners allow to insert a sequence of characters, as Prefix and/or Suffix, in their output. Check the instructions on the configuration of these devices

you can usually configure the last character the handscanner "types" by scanning a specific QR code in the user manual.
Its often "Enter" or "Tab"
You can configure both scanners to have different termination characters and if you implment you application to differentiate between the two, you can easlily differentiate the two handscanneras from on another.
